# How to format help-like document in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I need to write some documentation for the functions I have created and I'd like to mimic the style from R Help documentation. My document will be in PDF, so as the downloable vignettes for R packages. Precisely speaking, I want to create an output like attached excerpt from `dplyr` documentation below:
[image]

Could anyone know how it is done? Is it a table with no border in `Latex` or just some text-position adjusting? What is the best way to mimic it in `Rmarkdown`?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something obvious here, but if you have R code (functions) you want to distribute, and you want them documented as in an R package... Why not roll them into a package?

Comment: You could create a `<table></table>` with no borders... Adding all the pezaz (links, code typing) could take some work, though.

Comment: @duckmayr Actually, I don't know a thing about building R packages and what I need is a quick solution. But maybe there's some source about how to write a documentation of package, which I could base on?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I have copied some example table and it didn't work properly with pdf_document type of output. Maybe there are some settings that need to be specified additionally to use `html` in `pdf_document`?

Comment: @jakes It would likely take you less time to learn how to throw your code in a package (and consequently get the documentation formatting you desire) than figuring out how to create the formatting yourself, particularly with the advent of tools like [`devtools`](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools) and excellent, accessible guides such as Hadley's [R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) or [Karl Broman's primer](https://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/).

Comment: How to build a package is one the most documented things on the internet. https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments, I believe the best solution here is to actually just put your code in a package. You seem hesitant or intimidated by that task, but it's really as easy as can be, which I'll briefly demonstrate for you.

Suppose you have the function

```
example_function <- function(x) {
    return(x * 2)
}
```

that you want/need to distribute, preferably with some documentation. Here's how you could do that in an R package relatively painlessly. We'll add documentation comments Roxygen-style:

```
#' Example function
#'
#' This is just an example function that multiplies its argument by two.
#'
#' @param x A numeric vector
#'
#' @return A numeric vector equal to \\code{x} multiplied by two.
#' @export
example_function <- function(x) {
    return(x * 2)
}
```

Then we'll let [`devtools`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=devtools) do some of the heavy lifting for us. First we use it to set up the necessary package structure:

```
pkg_path <- "/tmp/examplePackage" # Wherever you want your package to be on your machine
devtools::create(pkg_path, rstudio = FALSE)
```

Then we put the file with our example function above in the `R/` subdirectory of the package folder `devtools` made for us (in my case the code is now in the file `/tmp/examplePackage/R/example_function.R`.

Then we can simply run the command

```
devtools::document(pkg_path)
# Updating examplePackage documentation
# Loading examplePackage
# Writing NAMESPACE
# Writing example_function.Rd
```

And `devtools` + [`roxygen2`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=roxygen2) takes care of all the documentation magic for us. You can now `devtools::install()` to make the helpfiles available to R:

```
devtools::install(pkg_path)
?examplePackage::example_function
```

[image]

or `build_manual` to create the fancy PDF manual you mentioned:

```
devtools::build_manual(pkg_path)
# Hmm ... looks like a package
# Creating pdf output from LaTeX ...
# Saving output to ‘/tmp/examplePackage_0.0.0.9000.pdf’ ...
# Done
```

[image]